# Neutron double differential capture cross section

Tags: neutrons, scattering-cross-section, absorption

Can one define what is the double differential capture cross section for a neutron, and how one would construct an experiment to calculate the double differential cross section as a function of energy and angle on a target material? Which quantities would you need to measure to calculate this quantity as a function of primary neutron energy and scattering angle?